# Unable to download Metadata WSDL from Org

Tags: apex, integration, metadata-api, wsdl

Related to this other question [Discover Schema of Source + Metadata XML formats](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/353406/256) I am trying to download the Metadata API WSDL file from the Orgs URL https://ServInstance.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/metadata using this simple Apex code:

```
public Dom.Document mdApiWsdl() {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/wsdl/metadata');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(reqquest);
    return response.getBodyDocument();
}
```

The issue I face is that the page is not a WSDL XML document but a strange HTML page simulating it. In a browser, it's possible to download the file as XML but in Apex code I couldn't find a way.

Why is Salesforce preventing us from downloading this single WSDL?

Comment: In Apex did you try reading it via `XmlStreamReader` ?

Comment: Yes I did but it an HTML page that pretends to be an XML.

Comment: Ok I see now. So you want a way to parse the response in XML format from Apex?

Comment: I understood the issue, but dont know how to solve this. So the same response comes if you use a postman too.  The only time it works if you already have logged in to the browser and your session is active. Then it returns you the xml format. Now I am not sure how to pass creds in the header, I tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an authentication error html page because you didn't include the sid cookie in the request?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I just forgot to add that line to my question code. I adjusted the code now. But even with authentication, it won't work. Nagendra's assessment is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular page is expecting a `sid` session cookie rather than an Authorization header. You'll need a full UI session and then pass that session id into the Cookie header.

E.g.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/wsdl/metadata');
request.setMethod('GET');
//request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Cookie','sid='+UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```