# Penalties? - Code ran in seconds yesterday, today it times out

Tags: governorlimits, cpulimit, gack

In the context of my previous question on how to "[Discover Schema of Source + Metadata XML formats](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353406)" I have found a great [library to do simple XPath in Apex](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/apex-xpath).

Running this query on 1 MB Metadata API WSDL found 900 matches in a few seconds.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/wsdl/metadata');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Cookie','sid=' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

Blob wsdl = new Http().send(request).getBodyAsBlob();
XPath schema = new XPath( wsdl.toString() );

System.debug( SCHEMA.find('/definitions/types/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType').size() );
```

**Today it fails with GACKs or timeouts in my scratch org. Am I harming CPU or Stack soft governors and get a penalty today?**

Comment: Do you still get this CPU timeout problem if you disable logging (e.g. delete all TraceFlags in the org, and do not open Developer Console)? If not, it's probably just a debugging issue, which means you'll need to get ingenuous with your unit test writing skills.

Comment: You are so right! That indeed was the reason. I configured the Dev Console in my scratch org from FINEST TO NONE and ignored it ALWAYS. Always was FINEST. Maybe you also know why. I am happy to see your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU governor limit includes the time spent by the system writing to the log file, so the more detailed the logs, the more you risk running into a CPU limit exceeded problem. Maximum level logging can easily balloon the execution time 5-10 times (or more) what it would be for a user with logging disabled (the default mode). For example, even a natural two second execution time could easily hit 20 seconds with max logging enabled. When debugging, try to set your "[trace flags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm)" only as high as you need them, and set those flags only on classes that you need them for, if possible.